# Use Rosyln to rewrite switch blocks to if/else

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm new to roslyn so I'm looking for some pointers or sample code to start doing what I want.

I have a lot of code that is similar to this (it was generated by a tool)

```
switch (boolVariable)
{
    case false:
    {
        str = "blahblah";
        break;
    }
    case true:
    {
        str = "somethingelse";
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        str = "ughthiswouldnevergethit";
        break;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is detect and then rewrite the syntax to something that is more efficient and developer friendly

```
if(boolVariable)
{
   str = "somethingelse";
}
else
{
   str = "blahblah";
}
```

Essentially I am wanting to optimize out all switches that are on boolean values.

Comment: Why not rewrite it to `str = boolVariable ? "somethingelse" : "blahblah"` instead?

Comment: @DStanley Are you sure about that? I've seen MS devs use Roslyn to enforce coding standards by creating warnings when devs leave curly braces off if/else statements, and include "fixers" that integrate with Intellisense. Seems Matt's question is in the same vein.

Comment: I always thought this feature was acting as "rules" for the code what would be flagged when broken, not that it actively changed it. And if the code is something you almost never really touch the innards of, then seal it and leave it. If not then refactor when you see it.

Comment: @Mark That would be ideal but the above code is simpliefied, there are some blocks that within the true case, there is another switch on another expression. It can get 4-5 levels deep, doing it inline would be pretty crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use CSharpSyntaxRewriter, below is the code to achieve that (with simple case, you can extend from that)

(You should download [Syntax Visualizer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Syntax%20Visualizer) extension  or go to a simple online version [CSharp SyntaxTree](https://nhabuiduc.github.io/CSharpSyntaxParser/)  in order to understand more about Syntax Tree)

```
string code = ReadText("Case6.cs"); // get source code as string for a class
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
CompilationUnitSyntax root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
Compilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("assembly", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[]
{
    mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly),
               MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(Stack<>).Assembly)
});

var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var myRewriter = new MyRewriter(semanticModel);
var result = myRewriter.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
var str = result.ToString();

// below are classes for Rewriter
public class MyRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private SemanticModel semanticModel;

    public MyRewriter(SemanticModel semanticModel)
    {
        this.semanticModel = semanticModel;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitSwitchStatement(SwitchStatementSyntax node)
    {
        var result =  base.VisitSwitchStatement(node);

        // detect your case:
        // first check if the expression in switch is bool type?
        var typeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node.Expression);

        if(typeInfo.Type.SpecialType != SpecialType.System_Boolean)
        {
            return result;
        }

        // okie we make the conversion here
        // find true statement
        var trueSection = node.Sections
                .First(f => f.Labels.First().ToString().Contains("true"));
        var falseSection = node.Sections
                .First(f => f.Labels.First().ToString().Contains("false"));

        var trueStatement = trueSection.Statements.Count == 1
                        ? trueSection.Statements.First()
                        : SyntaxFactory.Block(trueSection.Statements);
        var falseStatement = falseSection.Statements.Count == 1
                        ? falseSection.Statements.First()
                        : SyntaxFactory.Block(falseSection.Statements);

        var ifStatement = SyntaxFactory.IfStatement(node.Expression,
            trueStatement,
            SyntaxFactory.ElseClause(falseStatement));

        //NOTE that: this class will remove all break statements
        // it will not be correct if break in loop, you can base on that to 
        // write more accurately
        var breakRemover = new BreakRemover();

        result = breakRemover.Visit(ifStatement);

        return result;
    }
}

public class BreakRemover : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitBreakStatement(BreakStatementSyntax node)
    {
        // should add further check to make sure break statement is in
        // switch, the idea is find closest ancestor must be switch (not
        // for, foreach, while, dowhile)
        return SyntaxFactory.EmptyStatement();
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitly helped me get on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: The links are broken and/or have moved.Syntax Visualizer page does not exist anymore, and CSharpSyntaxTree gives a "The service is unavailable". The Syntax Visualizer now forms part of the .NET Compiler Platform SDK - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Syntax%20Visualizer.
I tried to update the answer to fix the link issues, but got rejected by 3 out of 5 of the reviewers, some of the comments stating defacement of the answer and promoting a product or service, although it was just updating the link to the new location. :( So much for trying to help others by fixing broken links...